# Injecting Controller with $scope

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I am trying to understand the the basic of AngularJS. I picked up a sample code in code project. Below is the code

### index.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="MyAngular" data-ng-controller="LandingPageController">
<head>
    <title data-ng-bind="models.helloAngular"></title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" data-ng-model="models.helloAngular" />
    <h1>{{models.helloAngular}}</h1>


    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MyAngular")
</body>
</html>
```

### MyAngular.js

```
var MyAngular = angular.module('MyAngular', []);
MyAngular.controller('LandingPageController', LandingPageController);
```

### LandingPageController.js

```
var LandingPageController = function($scope)
{
    $scope.models = {
        helloAngular: 'I work!',
    };
}
LandingPageController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

The above works fine. However, I am having difficulties understand the line below

```
LandingPageController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Why this line is necessary and what is the implication of not having this line?

When I remove that line , I am not seeing any changes in the output.

-Alan-

Comment: [Plenty of questions](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20%22%24inject%22) about this already

Comment: That will be helpful ...